# How can I automatically draw frames around all elements on a page?

Tags: spacing, framed, debugging, layout

Fine-tuning the layout and spacing of elements in a document is often a guessing game. It would be great if LaTeX could display the spatial extensions of all elements (float, subfigure, minipage, display math blocks, tikzpicture, etc) on the page by drawing frames around them. Is there a general way of doing this?

Comment: Not really.  Adding a frame around a tikzpicure is easiest, using `\draw (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);`  You can add \fbox around almost anything, although it takes up space.  The float package can add frames around floats.  There is the framed package.  It might be easier to change the background color, but you would still need to treat each element separately.